# Spring Boot + Spring insight

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-boot, monitoring, spring-insight

in the past I worked with Spring Insight (tc runtime with STS) and I found it nicely to have the possibility to have a look at the performance of my server.

Now I would have the possibility to use the insight agent in other applications. For example I would it inbound in a jetty container or better in spring-boot application (only for development purpouses). Is there any person that has done this, and can explain me how to configure it?

Txs

Comment: Have you looked at the metrics that Spring Boot Actuator gives you? Not exactly the same as the dashboard features provided by Insight, but a lot of the data you're looking for you can find in Actuator https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Comment: Tank you for you're comment. Yes I saw it. It's not really the same, but you're right a lot of infos can give them.